# Get name of element using xmllint

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

Lets say I have this xml:

```
<Root>
    <Node size="Foo" />
<Root>
```

In order to get the values of attributes I run this command:

```
echo "<Root><Node size='foo' /></Root>"  | xmllint -xpath "/Root/Node/@size" -
```

(note the `-` at the end)

And this will return `foo`.

**Now my question is how can I have xmllint return me the name of the element which is `Node`?**

I have tried doing:

```
echo "<Root><Node size='foo' /></Root>"  | xmllint -xpath "/Root/Node/name()" -
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath you're using requires XPath 2.0, while xmllint supports only XPath 1.0.

Change your XPath to this XPath 1.0 expression,

```
name(/Root/Node)
```

and you'll echo the name of the selected node, `Node`, as requested.